# Whats wrong with my code. Im trying to color a table view controller

Tags: ios, swift, colors, tableview

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let green: UIColor = UIColor(red: 79, green: 255, blue: 110, alpha: 1)

    let lightGreen: UIColor;(red: 190, green: 225, blue: 211, alpha: 1)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let greenGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), [lightGreen.CGColor, green.CGColor],[0, 1],

        let backgroundPath = UIBezierPath(rect:  CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height)),
        CGContextSaveGState(context),
        backgroundPath.addClip(),

        CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, greenGradient, CGPointMake(160, 0), CGPointMake(160, 568),

            UInt32(kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation) | UInt32 (kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation)),

        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
```

i have been trying to debug this for about an hour and the build fails everytime.

Comment: can you elaborate `build fails everytime`?

Comment: line 7: pattern variable binding cannot appear, 8: use of unresolved identifier "BackgroundPath", 9: Variable used within its own initial value, 11: expected ',' separator, 13: expected expression in list of expressions and expected ')' in expression list, 14: expected declaration.     (13 and 14 not shown in initial code. 13 is a curly bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the color is not getting worked,

try this for setting colors

```
let green = UIColor(red: 79/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 110/255.0, alpha: 1)

let lightGreen = UIColor(red: 190/255.0, green: 225/255.0, blue: 211/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: the top fixed, but the bottom is still giving me errors.

Comment: `the top fixed` you mean the green is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You have added a semicolon in 2nd line:

```
let lightGreen: UIColor;(red: 190, green: 225, blue: 211, alpha: 1)
```

Remove this semicolon. It will work fine.